# Change link text to icon

Tags: php, jquery

Hello I need change text to icon in my menu after hover on it.
I am getting data from db, so I need do it dynamically.

**php in while**

```
       echo'<li style="width: ' . $row['item_width'] . 'px;">
    <a href="stranky/' . $nazev . '/1/' . $row['id'] . '" 
style="background-color: #' . $row['item_color'] . ';" alt="'. $row['item_name'] . '" 
       class="menu_data" id="search">'. $row['item_name'] . '</a>';
```

**js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){


        $(".menu_data" ).mouseover(function() {
          var icon = $(this).attr('id');
          $(this).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-'+icon+'"></span>')
        });
        $(".menu_data" ).mouseout(function() {
          var name = $(this).attr('alt');
          $(this).html(name)
        });

      });

    </script>
```

But it doesn't looks like nice. Have someon better idea?

Comment: "doesn't looks like nice". Why? Mind posting a screenshot? Preferably how you want it to look and how it does look right now.

Comment: http://zssever.damidev.com/ look.. when you mouse over changed icon, it isn't nice.